# Why is this so much faster?

Tags: matlab, loops

When I do these equivalent operations in MatLab, the first runs at 24.158371 seconds (the for loop).  The second runs at 0.004976 seconds (logical indexing).  What could MatLab possibly be doing that makes this run so much faster?  This has to still be O(n) time, right?

```
t = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,100000);
fd = 1e3;
tau = 1e-6;


% Calculate arbitrary function using a loop
tic
for tind = 1:length(t)
    tester(tind) = cos(2*pi*fd*t(tind))/(2*pi*fd.*t(tind));
end
toc

pause; disp('Press a key');
% Same calculation with logical indexing
tic
tester2 = cos(2*pi*fd.*t)./(2*pi*fd.*t);
toc
```

Comment: Your first loop represents a much more high-level way of doing the same thing as in the second; i.e. scripts are not optimalized much it seems.

Comment: This confirms the fact that Matlab loops suck and should be avoided like the plague if there's any way of using matrices.

Comment: @Reinderien - No, you are simply wrong. The problem in the loop is that tind was NEVER preallocated. So what happened is every pass through the loop, the array tind had to be reallocated in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest cost in your first loop actually comes from dynamically resizing the array `tester`. Each time through the loop, Matlab has to copy the existing array to a new location in memory with room for the extra element. So, that's an O(n) operation for each iteration of the loop. If you pre-allocate the array, it will run much faster, e.g.

```
tic
tester = zeros(100000,1);
for tind = 1:length(t)
    tester(tind) = cos(2*pi*fd*t(tind))/(2*pi*fd.*t(tind));
end
toc
```

On my system, I get 11.3 seconds for the original loop, 0.0013 seconds for the vectorized version and 0.010 seconds for the loop with the memory for `tester` preallocated.

It's worth mentioning that many other languages with resizable arrays allocate additional space in chunks proportional to the current size of the array, so the cost of building an array by appending one element at a time is only O(n log n), so this is a particular deficiency of Matlab.

Answer (score 5):

The R2011a release of MATLAB makes this sort of thing much faster (what? You haven't got that release yet? Get downloading!), see the [release note](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/rn/bstrgub-1.html#bsy83rt-1). On my machine, the first loop takes 0.02 seconds, and the second takes 0.004 seconds. So, pre-allocation is still a good idea, but you're not in quite such a bad place if you can't do that.